# Is there any way to get only the custom roles?

Tags: 8, users

I would like a list of all custom roles.
Currently I am loading all of them using

`$roles = $this->entityManager->getStorage('user_role')->loadMultiple();`

but am wondering if there is any function that only brings the custom ones besides manually creating a static filter for the Anonymous, Authenticated and Administrator.

Comment: The [Role entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21Role.php/class/Role/8.8.x) doesn't really make any distinction.  Looking at the roles in my own db (filter `config` table by `name LIKE user.role%`) the only potential contender I can see is that the three default ones have a dependency on `_core`, so you could check that via getDependencies, but that feels arguably flakier than a static filter to me.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stevekeiretsu said in a comment ->

The Role entity doesn't really make any distinction. Looking at the roles in my own db (filter config table by name LIKE user.role%) the only potential contender I can see is that the three default ones have a dependency on _core, so you could check that via getDependencies, but that feels arguably flakier than a static filter to me.

So for Drupal 8 there is no function defined.